# dojo dijit.tree getChildren() not returning all tree nodes

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am using dojo 1.10.4 and have noticed that the dijit.tree getChildren() function only returns children (tree) nodes that are expanded (displayed and visible) in the dijit.tree. How can I loop through all of the dijit.tree tree nodes regardless of whether or not they are displayed and visible?

- I can easily loop through all of the underlying data store elements but I am trying to locate specific tree nodes so that I can style them using "node.labelNode.style".
- I could programmatically expand all of the dijit.tree nodes prior to calling getChildren() but I wish to preserve the user's view of the dijit.tree.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you are after, but that's how we are expanding all the nodes, which is similar to your task, getting all the nodes from the tree. I believe with a simple modification you will be able to achieve your task

Assume that we have a function for expanding the tree nodes, which we are going to call

```
    this._expandTree(this._tree.rootNode);
```

and the function itself

```
    _expandTree: function (node) {
                if (node.hasChildren()) {
                    var currentNode;
                    for (var i = 0; i < node.getChildren().length; i++) {
                        currentNode = node.getChildren()[i];                            
                        this._expandTree(currentNode);
                    }
                }
            },
```

Comment: Thanks for response but the problem is that I want to search thru all of the dijit.tree nodes regardless of whether or not they are expanded without expanding the tree nodes so I can preserve the user's view of the dijit.tree

Comment: that's what it does ... this loops through the whole tree, I told you to modify the name of it and do whatever you need to do with it. "expandTree" is just the name of our function that loops through all nodes.

Comment: Thank you. Had not realized that was what the code was doing. Appreciate the help!

Comment: I think the _expandTree function won't be able to loop thru the whole tree unless it's expanded manually or via _expandNode() or autoExpand:true property. The reason being is, the children will be placed on the DOM only when the tree node is expanded.